# MySQL Query to Bulk Delete Spam Wordpress Users

Tags: mysql, wordpress

My membership website has been inundated with spam sign ups. One thing I noticed is a lot of the spammers emails are *@hotmail.com*.

What I want to do is delete all users who are subscribers and have a @hotmail email address.

The users data are in two tables `wp_users` and `wp_usermeta` and as far as I understand, I need to delete the data in both tables to effectively remove the users. I haven't managed to find a query that can delete all users data from mysql across the two tables.

I can delete the users in the wp_user table with this query

```
DELETE 
FROM  wp_users 
WHERE  user_email LIKE  "%@hotmail%"
```

But I also need to delete the data from the `wp_usersmeta` table and also make sure I am only deleting subscribers (`meta_key = wp_capabilities and meta_value = subscriber`).

Any ideas how I can do this? Are there users data in any other tables that I'm missing? Subscribers do not have any posts associated with them.

I've seen some plugins for spam sign ups but they are preventative. Right now, I need a way to get rid of these annoying spammers emails.

Comment: did you try `<?php wp_delete_user( $id, $reassign ); ?>` of course within a loop where you retrieve user ids of all users with hotmail

Comment: My problem is its quite a lot of users that need to be deleted (approx 10 000). I tried to delete 900 users at once within the admin section but my server couldn't handle that many at once.

Comment: Is it possible for you to first delete all records from meta and then from the main table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [INNER JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) when using [DELETE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) in MySQL.

```
DELETE
FROM  wp_users 
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id
WHERE  wp_users.user_email LIKE  "%@hotmail%" AND [etc, etc.]
```

This solution gives you two (or maybe more ;-)) problems: 1) you can't reassign posts and links (if you want) and 2) you have to deal with JSON values in MySQL.

A better way is to use WordPress functions for the job. You can use [get_users](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) to search for users and [wp_delete_user](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_user) to delete the user.

```
<?php $args = array(
    'blog_id'      => $GLOBALS['blog_id'],
    'role'         => 'subscriber',
    'search'       => '*@hotmail.com'
 );

$blogusers = get_users($args);
    foreach ($blogusers as $user) {
        wp_delete_user( $user->ID, $reassign );
    }
?>
```

Please read the [Function Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page): it will help you solve this problem and future problems.

Comment: Yes that's it. Thanks bro, dank u wel!