# Wordpress - delete all users without role

Tags: wordpress, spam

We have more than 900.000 spam users! and they haven't any role. We want to delete all spam users and their meta.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18610665/mysql-query-to-bulk-delete-spam-wordpress-users) and [this link](http://wpquestions.com/question/showChrono/id/8845) we can delete users based on role but our spam users doesn't have any role.

This query return real users:

```
SELECT user_id FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'wp_capabilities'
```

In `usermeta` spam users doesn't have `capabilities` key.

We want remove spam users with database query.

Comment: I think it will need more queries. As you said "In usermeta spam users doesn't have capabilities key." So you can get spam user list easily , right? like find user who do not have KEY..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for resolve you can use subquery and in operator

```
delete from wp_users where ID not in
(select user_id from wp_usermeta where meta_key = 'wp_capabilities')

select user_id from wp_usermeta where user_id not in
(select ID from wp_users)
```

Comment: Works very well, thank you! Your 2nd query was supposed to say DELETE I believe. DELETE FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT ID from wp_users);